# lists that dont have lists in the url

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I've noticed that some lists on our 2013 don't come under lists when using site contents.  bit confusing so an example should make it clearer

I have a custom list called projectgate and the URL is `https://xxxxxxxxx/projects/1625382710/Lists/Project%20Gate/AllItems.aspx.`  notice the lists in the url.

I have another custom list called projectwise that doesn't have lists in the URL `https://xxxxxxxxx/projects/1625382710/ProjectWiseProjectLink/AllItems.aspx.`

I'm confused.

Comment: It is a list or a document library?

Comment: @jpussacq its a list

Comment: The second one must be a library

Comment: @GintasK its a list i assure you

Comment: That's very strange. Take a look at http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2010/03/25/sharepoint-url-basics-aspx/ All SharePoint Lists are populated under "Lists" folder. Does it say "List" in the ribbon as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone could have done this using powershell or .NET.

Comment: This is correct, when programmatically creating lists you can specify any url structure you like. The same goes for lists created via a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like One is list and Other is library. Could you please run thebelow PowerShell and confirm it.

to check if it is library:

```
Get-SPWeb https://xxxxxxxxx/projects/1625382710/ | Select -ExpandProperty Lists | Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary" } | Select Title
```

if `ProjectWiseProjectLink` showed here then it is library.otherwise

To check if it is List:

```
Get-SPWeb https://xxxxxxxxx/projects/1625382710/ | Select -ExpandProperty Lists | Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPList" } | Select Title
```